# Control the appearance of a Google Map from My Maps

Tags: jquery, maps, appearance

I'm having a difficult time looking for instructions on how to customize the appearance of an embed map instance I've created in Google Maps and stored in My Maps. There are jquery plugins for generating and manipulating new map instances, but I haven't found any on how to manipulate *existing* map instance from My Maps.

Does anyone have a recommendation for a jquery plugin that can manipulate the appearance of a My Maps map instance?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: import the RSS/KML feed into a map overlay:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services.html#XML_Overlays